# Basic Widgets Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS

Tags: operations-dashboard

What is needed to create new widgets for Operations Dashboard?

Is there a simple basic instructions?

Have no programming experience.

And how to set a widgets available to a user?

Answer (score 1):

it can be done using the ArcGIS API for Javascript, check the following link:

[Extend Operations Dashboard](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/operations-dashboard-extensibility-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the out of the box solution then you don’t programming knowledge to use the widgets available. This was a good resource https://youtu.be/Yw6z6Xzi9UQ . However if you need to create brand new widgets then you would need arcgis api for JavaScript